# LogCat where my SQLite statement is red but the app runs fine

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making an android app where there is a basic login function. I already created the accounts. It logins successfully but I am bothered by an error (don't know why it's an error if it works fine). This shows red:

```
E/DatabaseHelper(20507): SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_name = 'admin' AND u_password = '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3'
```

Here's the code from the DatabaseHelper

```
public UserModel getUser(String user_name, String user_password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USER + " WHERE "
            + KEY_USERNAME + " = '" + user_name + "' AND " + KEY_PASSWORD + " = '" + user_password + "'";

    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c != null)
        c.moveToFirst();

    UserModel ur = new UserModel();
    ur.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
    ur.setUname((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_USERNAME))));
    ur.setPassword(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PASSWORD)));
    ur.setPrivilege(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRIVILEGE)));

    return ur;
}
```

And here's the call:

```
UserModel user = new UserModel();
user = db.getUser(username, pw);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling "Log.e" which brings up an error message (in red text). You should change it to Log.d (for debug), or Log.i (for information), or something else other than "e" since it is not really an error and no exception is present.